# Google Hangouts URI functionality to start Hangout chat or video call etc

Tags: api, uri, skype, google-hangouts

We want to add Google Hangouts functionality to our web app/ client applications. We have a global address book in our browser based web application. For each user, we want to have an icon to start a chat and an icon to start a video call directly in Hangouts. We doesn't want to start an Hangouts an Air. It should als work on mobile devices when the Hangout app is installed.

E.x., Skype offers an [URI API reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/office/dn745882%28v=office.15%29.aspx), actually that's what we are looking about. It's easy to implement because you just can just set the value of your anchor tag’s href attribute to the Skype URI.

Is that also possible with Google Hangouts? I couldn't find anything in the API documentation.